# Discord.js Missing Permissions while adding user to role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am running into an "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions " error when trying to add a member to a role. My code is:

```
const role: Role = await this.getRole(requestingUser, roleId);
const member: GuildMember = await this.getGuildMember(memberId);

await member.roles.add(role);
```

The client should have the intents it needs. This is the code we use for getting the client instance for the calls:

```
  async getClient () {
    if (!this.client) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-async-promise-executor
      this.client = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const client = new Client({
          intents: [
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
          ]
        });

        client.on('error', async (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });

        client.on('ready', async () => {
          resolve(client);
        });

        await client.login(this.botToken);
      });
    }
    return this.client;
  }
```

The bot does have have 'manage roles' permission:

[image: Screen shot showing permissions]

The stack trace once it hits discord.js code:

```
 DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions 
   at RequestHandler.execute (/usr/src/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13) 
   at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) 
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) 
   at async RequestHandler.push (/usr/src/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14) 
   at async GuildMemberRoleManager.add (/usr/src/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js:124:7)
```

This is using discord.js 13.6.0 and node.js 16.6.0

Any ideas?

Comment: The role must be above the bot's highest role

Comment: Adjusting the role permissions and moving it up near the top of the role list helped. Do you want to provide an answer, so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a role is higher than a user or bot's highest role, it's basically read-only for you, even if you have the `ADMINISTRATOR` permission. The only thing that bypasses this is being the owner. Either move the bot's role up, the role being given down, or do a check and send an error message if it's higher

```js
if (
  role.position >= guild.me.roles.highest.position ||
  !guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")
) return interaction.reply({
  content: "I don't have permissions to grant this role!",
  ephemeral: true
})
```